# Mongodb find documents and exclude the duplicates at the same time

Tags: mongodb, find, distinct, where-clause

Imagine I have this documents:

```
{name:'pep', team:'barcelona', age:24}
{name:'boris', team:'madrid', age:52}
{name:'erdem', team:'barcelona', age:41}
{name:'robert', team:'barcelona', age:19}
```

I want to filter this list by older than 20 and distinct the results by team so I'd have have this results:

```
{name:'pep', team:'barcelona', age:24}
{name:'boris', team:'madrid', age:52}
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?

Comment: What happened to "erdem"?

Comment: There's already a result with 'barcelona' team (pep).

Comment: And why do you choose "pep" not "erdem" are your documents sorted or you just want the first document for each team?

Comment: I actually don't mind whether if it is pep or erdem, I've just chose it cause it was the first in the list. BTW I know it doesn't have much sense with that example, but yea, i'm looking for that query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`.aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method which gives access to the aggregation pipeline. The first stage in the pipeline is the the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage where you filter out those documents that don't match your criteria. The last stage in the pipeline is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage where your group your documents by `team` and use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator operator to return the first or last document for each group.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "age": { "$gt": 20 } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$team", "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks but I try it and get "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."